# Lebesgue and counting measure not interchangeble in integral and integrand?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

While preparing for my exam, I stumbled upon the following two integrals:

$\int{\mu(D_{x}) m(dx) }$  and $\int{m(D_{y}) \mu(dy) }$

Where $D_{x,y}$ are the sections with respect to x and y for $D:= [(x,y)   \in [0,1] \\ $x$[0,1] : x=y ]$ (So $D_x = [y \in [0,1] : (x,y) \in D] $ )

$\mu$ denotes the counting measure (thus infinite for [0,1]), $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

The integral runs from 0 to 1.

My reader suggests that these integrals are not equal, but to me it seems that both integrals will have an 'infinite term' because of the counting measure and a 'finite term' because of the Lebesgue measure on the interval of finite length.

Can someone please explain why these integrals are not equal? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D_{y}$ is by definition the set of $x$ such that $(x,y) \in D$.  Note that $y$ is *fixed*.  So, for each fixed single $y$, $D_{y}$ is by definition $\{y \}$ since only $(y,y) \in D$ by definition of $D$.

Now, $m$ is Lebesgue measure, so $m(D_{y}) = m( \{y\}) = 0$, right?

So $\int_{[0,1]}  m(D_{y})\,d\mu = \int_{[0,1]} 0 \,d\mu = 0$.

Similarly, $D_{x}$ is by definition the set of $y$ such that $(x,y) \in D$.  Note that $x$ is *fixed*.  So, for each fixed $x$, $D_{x} = \{x \}$ since only $(x,x) \in D$ by definition of $D$.

Now, $\mu$ is counting measure, so $\mu( D_{x}) = \mu(\{x\}) = 1$, right?

So $\int_{[0,1]}  \mu(D_{x})\,dm = \int_{[0,1]} 1 \,dm = 1$.

So, the iterated integrals are not equal.  One equals $0$ while the other equals $1$.